# Freebase topic API deprecated

Tags: deprecated, freebase

I use Freebase Topi API for getting Details on topics like Actors.
However, it seems the old freebase API is being deprecated and googlecode.com api is being introduced.
Any idea how can I get the details of actors using the new APIs (Like movies, books, description, aliases and image for an actor)?

Regards

Answer (score 2):

Like this:

https://www.googleapis.com/freebase/v1-sandbox/topic/en/harrison_ford

For production use you'll need to apply for an API key at https://code.google.com/apis/console and include it in your requests.

Answer (score 1):

The new topic API is currently in beta; the Freebase staff have stated that it will be out of beta by the time the old API is deprecated; see [this post](http://lists.freebase.com/pipermail/freebase-discuss/2012-April/008844.html) to the freebase-discuss mailing list from Jason Douglas, one of the Freebase product managers.